# Java program stucks in XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml

Tags: java, rabbitmq, itext, xmlworkerhelper

I have this kind of issue now in Production that sometimes occurring. For context, I'm using RabbitMQ and a Consumer called email-service, RabbitMQ is my messaging server and email-service are the one responsible for converting the HTML string to PDF and sending it via Email. I'm using this method `XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml()` to parse HTML to PDF and it stuck sometimes without error on the logs that made my rabbitMQ UNACK all the message that is currently queued. Please see the code below:

```
                ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                log.info( "END OF ByteArrayOutputStream" );
                Document document = new Document();
                log.info( "END OF Document" );
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
                log.info( "END OF PdfWriter" );
                document.open();
                log.info( "END OF document.open();" );
                XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, 
                         new StringReader(fileAttachmentString)); // <--- sometimes stuck here
                log.info( "END OF XMLWorkerHelper" );
                document.close();
                log.info( "END OF document.close();" );
                byte[] bytes = outputStream.toByteArray();
                log.info( "END OF byte[] bytes = outputStream.toByteArray();" );
                DataSource dataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(bytes, "application/pdf");
                log.info( "END OF DataSource" );
                attachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(dataSource));
                attachmentPart.setFileName(filename);
                multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);
```

If this occurred, I need to restart email-service again so it will consume again the messages in RabbitMQ. I don't know what causing why it stuck there in some time.

Note: Sending of email is working after restart but suddenly stucks because of the issue above.

Update:

Please check also the thread dump, I think it is stuck on the SocketInputStream.socketRead0 when I check the inner logs in Thread Dump.

[image]

Comment: Does it always fail on the same input data? Does it fail after processing a certain number of records? Is there really no exception thrown? [`XMLWorkerHelper::parseXHtml`](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText5/java/5.5.9/com/itextpdf/tool/xml/XMLWorkerHelper.html#parseXHtml-com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter-com.itextpdf.text.Document-java.io.Reader-) is documented as throwing `IOException`. Is this code inside a try/catch?

Comment: @DavidConrad , no it does not stuck on the same input data and also on certain number  of records, it doesn't have any errors and I assure it to be on the try catch block. the last log I encountered is 'END OF document.open();' which above the line of the stuck statement.